# GnuTLS (tpmtools) api for signing data in a TPM

Tags: security, cryptography, tpm, gnutls

Recently I started working with a TPM (version 1.2), and after checking the oficial GnuTLS API, I was wondering which API functions are the correct ones to do all the crypto stuff inside the chip (sign certificates get pk+ keys etc...).

At the moment Im able of getting this data outside of the TPM so I can sign or get a private key in my C code but thats not what I want.

Thank all!

Comment: You can't get private keys out of the TPM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of events is something like this:

1. Invoke [`gnutls_tpm_key_list_get_url`](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/TPM-API.html#gnutls_005ftpm_005fkey_005flist_005fget_005furl) to get the list of the TPM keys.
2. Choose the key you want to sign with from the list and import it with [`gnutls_privkey_import_tpm_url`](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Using-keys.html#Using-keys).
3. Now you have the `gnutls_privkey_t` object you can use with the [abstract API](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Abstract-key-API.html#Abstract-key-API) just like any other key. In your case, you probably want to use `gnutls_privkey_sign_data` or one of the similar signing functions.

Keep in mind that going with this approach limits you to TPM 1.2. From [GnuTLS docs](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Trusted-Platform-Module.html#Trusted-Platform-Module):

> Note that we recommend against using TPM with this API because it is
>   restricted to TPM 1.2. We recommend instead to use PKCS#11 wrappers
>   for TPM such as CHAPS14 or opencryptoki15. These will allow using the
>   standard smart card and HSM functionality (see Smart cards and HSMs)
>   for TPM keys.

Comment: thanks you very much for answering, but that sequence needs to store the key  somewhere in the memory (under gnutls_privkey_t ) and that something I need to avoid, what I was looking for is something like 

1º get the data i want to sign/encrypt....
2º tell the GnuTLS to sign that data with this key referenced by some "uuiid"
calling something like gnutls_tpm_crypto_stuff(uuid_of_the_key,&data_i_want_to_sign)


thanks for telling about chaps and opencryptoki15 going to check it

Comment: @Arraiz I'm not sure what the problem is, but if your'e concerned that sensitive information about the key is somehow stored in `gnutls_privkey_t` -- there's no reason to be. The private key will never leave the TPM, because it can't. The only thing that's stored in `gnutls_privkey_t` is the TSS context, that allows the TSS to communicate with the TPM and identify the key (including the UUID).